# How fix my problem with tint color for UIBarButtomItem?

Tags: ios, swift

I try create menu button at navigation bar, i want to set only image without text. But if I try to set the image to “barButtomItem.image” then the color is automatically set to blue, can I fix it somehow?

[blue color for button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Anntn.jpg)

```
var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem {
        let button = UIBarButtonItem()
        button.image = UIImage(named: "menubtn")
        return button
}

rootVC.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuButton
```

Ok, i can set tintColor for button

```
var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem {
    let button = UIBarButtonItem()
    button.image = UIImage(named: "menubtn")
    button.tintColor = UIColor(named: "myGreenColor")
    return button
    }

rootVC.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuButton
```

But the color of the shadow also changes

[green shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GLMw.jpg)

can i set black color for shadow of button? or is it possible to somehow disable the function that automatically assigns a color to the image?

It also seems to me that this problem can be solved if you add a button to BarButtonItem and assign an image to it, I tried to do this using a storyboard, but I don’t know how to do it using code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this? I haven't tested though.

```
    var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem {
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "menubtn"), for: .normal)
        return UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
    }
    rootVC.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuButton
```